# Create Zendesk Ticket iOS v2

Tags: ios, swift3, zendesk-api

I'm just trying to have a form for users to create a ticket in my app. Nothing else is needed besides that.

I have used the methods here https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios_support_sdk/requests

Here is my code

```
//Create a configuration object
    let config = RequestUiConfiguration()
    config.subject = "App Ticket"
    config.tags = ["ios", "testing"]
    config.ticketFormID = 20

    //Present the SDK
    let requestScreen = RequestUi.buildRequestUi(with: [config])
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(requestScreen, animated: true)
```

But the screen that shows in my app doesn't have a send button or back. I also set the color to orange, but I don't see that change either.

```
Theme.currentTheme.primaryColor = UIColor.orange
```

[image: This is the output]

That bottom bar with the Zendesk logo just takes me to a zendesk page

I have the proper set up in app delegate as well

```
Zendesk.initialize(appId: "myAppID",
                   clientId: "myClientID",
                   zendeskUrl: "myURL")
Support.initialize(withZendesk: Zendesk.instance)
```